# Sliding Panel not working

Tags: c#, winforms

Anyone know how to create a sliding panel similar to Thread. I'm using thread but if the panel contains any component the threading looks lagy or not smooth. here's my code.

```
public int check, Cstatus = 0;
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (check == 1 && Cstatus == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 102; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                PanelSubButtons.Size = new Size(i, 403);
                Thread.Sleep(1);

            }
            check = 0; Cstatus = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (check == 0)
            {
                PanelSubButtons.Controls.Clear();
                PanelSubButtons.Controls.Add(new SubPanels.PanelResort(this));
                for (int i = 1; i <= 102; i++)
                {
                    PanelSubButtons.Size = new Size(i, 403);
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
                check = 1; Cstatus = 1;
            }
            else if (check == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 102; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    PanelSubButtons.Size = new Size(i, 403);
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
                PanelSubButtons.Controls.Clear();
                PanelSubButtons.Controls.Add(new SubPanels.PanelResort(this));
                for (int i = 1; i <= 102; i++)
                {
                    PanelSubButtons.Size = new Size(i, 403);
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
                check = 1; Cstatus = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

it works perfectly fine until the panels got some components inside.
I'm just asking if there's another easy way to make your panel slide in and out the same way this Thread.Sleep(1); do.

Comment: A `Thread` and a `Panel` have nothing in common. You are not using threading here, either. Can you go into more detail what you are looking for?

Comment: sorry. Noob here. Well as you can see on the code. I'm using Thread.Sleep(1); to make my panels looks like sliding while I'm only re-sizing its size. I'm looking for another way to make my panel really slide or re-size smoothly. Something like that.

Comment: For animations use a `Timer` with an `Interval` of `10-50ms`! In its `Tick` event you may want to use `floats` to control the animation.. - Remember that the human eye can't perceive anything faster that 16Hz, so 20-30Hz is ample!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, since there are many possibilities to make an *animated* panel and yours is one of them. I would sugges some improvements:

- try to extract and put repetitive code in one place only
- after you resize the component, refresh/redraw it
- try not to block the main UI thread - this can be achived for example using an asynchronous [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

One possible solution considering this points looks like this:

Create a controller class from which the UI element (in this case a Panel) can be resized and filled (the resize acceppts negative number in order to make the control smaller and positive number to make the control bigger):

```
public class ResizingPanelController
{
    public Panel PanelControl { get; private set; }

    public ResizingPanelController()
    {
        this.PanelControl = new Panel();
        // demo - in order to see the panel
        this.PanelControl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
    }

    public void ResizeControl(int delta)
    {
        var y = this.PanelControl.Size.Height;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var x = this.PanelControl.Size.Width;
            // do we need to increase or decrease
            var up = delta > 0;
            // set condition end regarding resize direction (make x bigger or smaller)
            var end = up ? x + delta : x - Math.Abs(delta);
            // evaluate condition regarding resize direction
            Func<int, int, bool> conditionIsMet = (value, limit) => up ? value < limit : value > limit;
            while (conditionIsMet(x, end))
            {
                // increase or decrease x regarding resize direction
                x = up ? x + 1 : x - 1;
                this.PanelControl.Size = new Size(x, y);
                await Task.Delay(10);
                // repaint controls
                this.PanelControl.Refresh();
            }
        }, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // create the controller
        var rpc = new ResizingPanelController();
        // add the panel to the form - the form has already two buttons
        this.Controls.Add(rpc.PanelControl);
        // set panel size
        rpc.PanelControl.SetBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);
        // add controls to the panel
        var buttonPlus = new Button();
        var buttonMinus = new Button();
        var label = new Label();
        buttonPlus.Text = "+";
        buttonMinus.Text = "-";
        label.Text = "Something to Show!";
        buttonPlus.SetBounds(1, 1, 50, 25);
        buttonMinus.SetBounds(1, 26, 50, 25);
        label.SetBounds(1, 51, 200, 25);
        rpc.PanelControl.Controls.Add(buttonPlus);
        rpc.PanelControl.Controls.Add(buttonMinus);
        rpc.PanelControl.Controls.Add(label);
        // resize panel
        this.buttonClosePanel.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                // make it smaller
                rpc.ResizeControl(-170);
            };
        this.buttonOpenPanel.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            // make it bigger
            rpc.ResizeControl(170);
        };
    }
```

Resizing works smoothly on my machine when the panel has some controls:

[image]

An alternative approach as suggested by @BenVoight would be to create an [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) method and call it for the desired panel element:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // add controls to the panel
        var buttonPlus = new Button();
        var buttonMinus = new Button();
        var label = new Label();
        buttonPlus.Text = "+";
        buttonMinus.Text = "-";
        label.Text = "Something to Show!";
        buttonPlus.SetBounds(1, 1, 50, 25);
        buttonMinus.SetBounds(1, 26, 50, 25);
        label.SetBounds(1, 51, 200, 25);
        panel1.Controls.Add(buttonPlus);
        panel1.Controls.Add(buttonMinus);
        panel1.Controls.Add(label);
        // resize panel
        this.buttonClosePanel.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                // make it smaller
                resizeControl(-250);
            };
        this.buttonOpenPanel.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            // make it bigger
            resizeControl(250);
        };
    }

    private async void resizeControl(int delta)
    {
        var y = panel1.Size.Height;
        var x = this.panel1.Size.Width;
        // do we need to increase or decrease
        var up = delta > 0;
        // set condition end regarding resize direction (make x bigger or smaller)
        var end = up ? x + delta : x - Math.Abs(delta);
        // evaluate condition regarding resize direction
        Func<int, int, bool> conditionIsMet = (value, limit) => up ? value < limit : value > limit;
        while (conditionIsMet(x, end))
        {
            // increase or decrease x regarding resize direction
            x = up ? x + 1 : x - 1;
            this.panel1.Size = new Size(x, y);
            await Task.Delay(10);
            // repaint controls for smooth view
            this.panel1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

It has the advantage, that is very simple to use and no other classes and special constructs are needed.

Comment: Using a background thread to control UI animation is nowhere near as good an idea as what TaW expressed in the comments -- use a UI timer.  An async task in the UI context would be ok too... but `Thread.Sleep` is incompatible with async.

Comment: @BenVoigt I removed the `Thread.Sleep` usage. The method is now using `Task.Delay`. Thanks for the remark. I'll try to rewrite the code to use a timer instead of async task.

Comment: Async task using `Task.Delay` is fine, but you don't use `Factory.StartNew` for that, just call an async method, so it runs async in UI context..

Comment: nice. very very nice :D thanks a lot for this sir.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have extended my answer. I hope I understood you correctly and the implementation is what you meant.